# Visual Studio overwrtes ApplicationManifest.xml during build in Azure Service Fabric project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I am just trying to setup a DNS service in my cluster for the communication between two micro services. I am following the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice. I have a service fabric project with service having stateless web api mode. I am setting the attribute ServiceDnsName like below in

```
<DefaultServices>

    <Service Name="ManageCustomer" ServiceDnsName="service1.application1">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="ManageCustomerType" InstanceCount="[ManageCustomer_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
```

But whenver I build the solution, Visual studio removes the added attribute from ApplicationManifest.xml file. Any idea how to solve this. Is there any way to set the same in ServiceManifest.xml file.

Comment: If I add that attribute and then do Rebuild All the attribute does not get erased. This is in VS2015 and Service Fabric SDK 2.6.220